# Simulate Network Delay Jasmine Unit Test with $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, httpbackend, angular-mock

I have an angularjs directive that uses an ng-mouseenter to trigger a call to the backend for data.  If the call to the backend goes longer than a certain time, a loading indicator is presented.

I'd like to test that the loading indicator gets presented when a network call is taking longer than that specified period of time.

Is there a way to simulate this delay with $httpBackend?

The code that triggers these actions (inside a directive):

```
scope.triggerPopover = function () {
            if (angular.element('.my-element-style').length === 0) {
                scope.detailProm = $timeout(function () {
                makeRESTCall(attrs.assetId || '');
              }, 200);  //waits this length before it makes any call to the backend

             //we want the loading icon to come a little bit later, because it will seem to flicker
             //when calls are fast
             scope.loadingProm = $timeout(function () {
                          showLoadingPopover();
                      }, 500);
                  }
             };
```

The html/directive use

```
<article my-directive ng-mouseenter="triggerPopover();"></article>
```

In the spec I have in the beforeEach()...

```
//mock the backend call
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/my/rest/endpoint')
            .respond(mockData);
```

The test with a hover:

```
describe('hover tests', function () {
        it('hovering over the article should make a loading element appear while waiting for a restangular call', function () {
            runs(function() {
                //it takes a few milliseconds for the mouseover to react
                //due to a timeout in the directive
                jQuery(jQuery('the-class-im-looking-for')[0]).mouseover();
            });

            waits(1000);

            runs(function() {
                console.log('I want to know if the loading popover was launched, but I need to set a delay in the $httpBackend?');
            })
        });
    });
```